# UserDefaults.standard not saving swift3 xcode 8

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Hello everybody I'm trying to build a simple one view program to call and navigate a voice menu, I cannot get the UserDefaults to properly save between closing of the app. I've also had issue with getting text to display in the UITextField, I would like for it to display if saved on launch, here is a description of vars:

UserInput - text field for employee ID (what needs saving)
Switch - if Save it is 1 save data, if 0 do not
Submit - submit button that should save the data and call.

This is my first iPhone app and any help would be much appreciated!

`enter code here`

```
   import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var UserInput: UITextField!



var SaveIt = true
var employID = ""
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.UserInput.delegate = self;
    UserInput.keyboardType = .numberPad
    if let current_eid = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "emp_ID") {
        UserInput.text = current_eid
    }

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func loadDefaults() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let UserInput = defaults.string(forKey: "emp_ID") {
        print(UserInput)

    } else {
        // focus on the text field if it's empty
        UserInput.becomeFirstResponder()        }

    UserInput.text = defaults.object(forKey: "emp_ID") as! String?
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
@IBAction func Switch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if (sender.isOn == true) {
        SaveIt = true
    }
    else{
        SaveIt = false
    }


}

@IBAction func Submit(_ sender: Any) {
    if (SaveIt) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(UserInput.text, forKey: "emp_ID")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
    let phone = "telprompt://1888247889pppp" + UserInput.text! + "p1p1p1p1";
    let url = URL(string:phone)!
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }           else { UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I suggest starting by making your key a simple, descriptive string that you use consistently.  Without getting too far into debugging, I'm suspicious that what you save and what you retrieve are different things.

Comment: I see what you mean, self.UserImput up top, but UserImput at the retrieve, I've updated the code to fix that and still it doesn't seem to store.

Comment: The naming `UserImput` as a static var and also as a text field is pretty confusing.

Comment: **Updated** I got some help from a co worker who knows swift much better than I, fixes are above and the app is working!